# What's meaning of %contact in this menu path?

Tags: emails

```
$items['admin/structure/contact/edit/%contact'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit contact category',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('contact_category_edit_form', 4),
    'access arguments' => array('administer contact forms'),
    'file' => 'contact.admin.inc',
);
```

How does it get the path `admin/structure/contact/edit/%contact` and what does it mean by `%contact`?

Answer (score 2):

All requests on admin/structure/contact/edit/[anything] will be handled by a Drupal form callback, `contact_category_edit_form()` in contact.admin.in` which returns a form array.

%contact means this parameter will be passed to `contact_load()` and the result will be pass to `contact_category_edit_form()` as first argument.

See [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

> Registered paths may also contain special "auto-loader" wildcard components in the form of '%mymodule_abc', where the '%' part means that this path component is a wildcard, and the 'mymodule_abc' part defines the prefix for a load function, which here would be named
>   `mymodule_abc_load()`.